# Disable basic_auth for Savon WSDL call

Tags: ruby, savon

Is it possible to disable authentication (basic_auth) when Savon attempts to retrieve the WSDL?

It appears that this changed somewhere around 2.0 or 2.1 and now the authentication headers are always being sent, which the server I am calling throws an error when this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Savon will perform basic auth only if you provide *:basic_auth* while creating the *Savon.client* object.

Comment: I finally just loaded the wsdl as a file as I wasn't able to get around this issue.